# Azure Stack Hub - Unable to Deploy Custom Image

Tags: azure, rhel, rhel8, azure-stack

Using a RHEL 8 Marketplace Item, I created a VM, upgraded it to RHEL 8.7.  Was able to deprovision the VM and then capture(image) the VM thru the portal.  I was able to create a VM from the image originally but now I am unable to.

When I attempt to create a VM with the image thru the portal, I get a ‘Conflict’ status for the VM resource.  The ‘networkinterfaces’, ‘publicIpAddresses’, and ‘networkSecurityGroups’ resources all show ‘Created’ or ‘OK’. The conflict error shows that the VM cannot be created from the image until the image has been successfully created.

Obviously, the image has already been created.

Thanks for any help!

I have not tried anything else.